prove $\frac{1}{1+6ab}+\frac{1} {1+6bc}+\frac{1}{1+6ca} \geq 1$.
the problem
If $a,b,c \geq 0$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$, prove that $\frac{1}{1+6ab}+\frac{1} {1+6bc}+\frac{1}{1+6ca} \geq 1$.
my idea
I used the inequality of Bermstrong and processed a bit what I obtained and got to:
$\frac{1}{1+6ab}+\frac{1} {1+6bc}+\frac{1}{1+6ca} \geq \frac{3}{(a+b+c)^2}$
I also tried proving that $\frac{1}{1+6ab}+\frac{1} {1+6bc}+\frac{1}{1+6ca} \geq a^2+b^2+c^2$, which is proved if we prove that $\frac{1}{1+6ab}\geq \frac{a^2+b^2}{2}$
I don't know what to do forward! I hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Aren't you done with Bermstrong (Titu) alone? We have $  3  = 3(a^2 + b^2 + c^2) \geq (a+b+c)^2$.

@CalvinLin Oooo... I didn't think to multiply with that 1 that equal $a^2+b^2+c^2$. Thank you!

Homogenizing such inequalities should become an intuitive step. $\quad$ If that didn't work, something else to try is $ \sum \frac{ c^2}{ c^2 + 6abc^2 } \geq \frac{ (a+b+c)^2 } { 1 + 6abc(a+b+c) } $.

By AM-HM and Rearrangement inequalities
$$\frac{\frac{1}{1+6ab}+\frac{1} {1+6bc}+\frac{1}{1+6ca} }3\ge \frac3{3+6(ab+bc+ca)}\ge \frac3{3+6(a^2+b^2+c^2)}=\frac13$$

By Titu, $$\sum_{\text{cyc}} \frac{1}{1+6ab} \ge \frac{9}{3+6(ab+bc+ca)}.$$Since $a^2+b^2+c^2 = 1 \ge ab+bc+ca$, we have $$\frac{9}{3+6(ab+bc+ca)} \ge \frac{9}{3+6(1)} = 1,$$as desired.

NOTE
$1$. $1 = a^2+b^2+c^2 \geq ab + bc + ca$
$2$. More the value in denominator less the overall value
So
$$\sum{\frac{1}{1+6ab}} \geq \frac{(1+1+1)^2}{3+6(ab+bc+ca)} \geq 1$$
